# Cmake script problems find_path

Tags: cmake, build-process

I have put these two lines in my Findglm.cmake file to point to the headers for this header library.

```
find_path(glm_INCLUDE_DIR NAMES glm.hpp matrix_transform.hpp type_ptr.hpp PATHS
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2/glm ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2/glm/gtc
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2/glm/gtx ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2glm/core)
set(glm_INCLUDE_DIRS ${glm_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

However when I generate my Xcode project it says that it cannot locate matrix_transform.hpp and type_ptr.hpp

I have played around with this some more it appears to only find the first argument I am wondering if I am using find path wrong ?

I am using cmake 2.8.8 darwinports.

Comment: I know that for one a FindX.cmake is used to find out where the include directories and library directories are for a generic os search and really what I am doing should be in my cmake.txt file but help me out.

Comment: Did you execute the following command: `include_directories($glm_INCLUDE_DIRS)` ?

Comment: Yes in my CMake.txt I executed 

find_package(DevIL REQUIRED)
include_directories(${DevIL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${DevIL_LIBRARY}) 

find_package(glfw REQUIRED)
include_directories(${glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${glfw_LIBRARIES})

find_package(glm REQUIRED)
include_directories(${glm_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Assimp REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Assimp_INCLUDE_DIRS})
set(LIBS ${LIBS} ${Assimp_LIBRARIES})

Comment: Am I using include_directories wrong ? Overwriting what is there?

Comment: Update: it appears that when I do message(${glm_INCLUDE_DIRS}) it only returns the first path... which is quite odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `find_path()` command returns single directory. In your case, it's the first dir, which contains the first file.

If this glm will be always located in your source dir, it would be sufficient to do

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2/glm
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2/glm/gtc
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2/glm/gtx
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/glm-0.9.3.2/glm/core)
```

The `find_path()` is used to determine dir somewhere outside of your project.

Comment: Your right I have been using it wrong I would have to loop through each one or do as above it would probably be smarter.